# Prove that if $H$ is a normal subgroup in $S_n$, and $H$ contains a $2$ cycle, then $H = S_n.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, solution-verification

> Prove that if $H$ is a normal subgroup in $S_n$, and $H$ contains a $2$ cycle, then $H = S_n.$

My attempt:

I have proved in a previous part of the question that given any two arbitrary $k$-cycles, there exists some permutation $\tau$ in $S_n$ such that the $k$ cycles are conjugate.

By this, any $2$-cycle in $S_n$ must be conjugate to our given $2$-cycle. Thus $H$ must contain every $2$-cycle in $S_n,$ by the definition of a Normal Subgroup.

But we know that any permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions. Therefore the $2$-cycles generate $S_n.$

As $H$ is a subgroup, it contains all compositions of its elements, as I is closed under the binary operation. It contains all compositions of all $2$-cycles in $S_n,$ thus $H$ must be equal to $S_n,$ as the $2$-cycles generate $S_n.$

Is my reasoning above correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: The statement in the title is wrong: $\{id, (1 2)\}$ is a proper subgroup of $S_3$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Is this subgroup normal? If you conjugate by (132), I'm getting (13), which isn't in this subgroup?

Comment: @srh As of my posting this comment, there was no mention of the word *normal* in the title.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier my apologies, I must have forgotten.